# Some file not served when run via Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, kestrel-http-server

I have a 'Hello World' Kestrel server generated by Yeoman  (as [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/your-first-mac-aspnet)).

```
yo aspnet
```

When I run the site via the command line everything work well:

```
dotnet run
```

If it's run through Visual Studio Code though `bootstrap.css`, `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js` don't load (404).

Looking at the F12 tools, they are actually coming from different locations.  When run via `dotnet run` they come from `https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/...`, but when run through Visual Studio Code the browser is looking for them in a local folder `~/lib/...`.

a. Why are the files being sourced differently depending on how I run the site?
b. How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run it from command line, it runs in production mode (no `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable set. When you run it from Visual Studio it sets the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Development`.

Inside your Razor files, you have a `<environments>` section which controls which files are served in which production mode. Depending on your environment/OS, you need to set the variable differently. i.e. in Linux you'd need to run `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development dotnet run`.

As for the reason why you get 404 when running in development mode, you probably need to copy over the `wwwroot` folder to your output directory, with this entry in your `project.json`.

```
"buildOptions": {
  "emitEntryPoint": true,
  "preserveCompilationContext": true,
  "copyToOutput": 
  [
    "wwwroot",
    "Views",
    "appsettings.json",
    "web.config"
  ]
},
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "Views",
    "appsettings.json",
    "web.config"
  ]
},
```

Though usually it should be necessary to add `wwwroot` to `copyToOutput`

Comment: Actually (rather stupidly for a boiler plate) there is no `lib` directory.

Comment: @the lib folder is usually created by either bower (when restoring bower dependencies) or by npm + gulp task (when you use npm). bower by default restores its dependencies in wwwroot/lib, while npm does it in proejctroot/npm_modules

Comment: You could try running `bower install` or `npm install` to restore the bower or npm dependencies, depending on which you run (you can see it by the existence of bower.json or package.json for npm)

Comment: `bower install` did it.  Thanks!